# C## convert symbols such as / * - + from string to int or double

Tags: c#, regex

convert symbols such as / * - + from string to int or double
or a way to ignore them when i'm converting them from string array to double array. i keep getting error("Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.")

```
Values.snum = textBox.Text;
var pattern = @"\s*([+*/-])\s*";

textBox.Text = Regex.Replace(textBox.Text, pattern, " $1 ");

int SOption = 0;

string[] parts = Values.snum.Split(' ');
int asize = parts.Length;

double[] num = new double[asize];
for (int c = 0; c < asize; c++)
{
   if ((parts[c] != "*") || (parts[c] != "/") || (parts[c] != "%" ) || (parts[c] != "+" ) || (parts[c] != "-"))
   {
      num[c] = Convert.ToDouble(parts[c]);
   }
}
```

Comment: What do the input strings look like?

Comment: `if ((parts[c] != "*") || (parts[c] != "*") || (parts[c] != "/") || (parts[c] != "%" ) || (parts[c] != "+" ) || (parts[c] != "-"))` is always true, I think you need `&&` here

Comment: it will look like 2*5+7/5-4

Comment: Why do you have the `(parts[c] != "*")` twice?

Comment: sorry i was testing it, one of them should not be their

Comment: Are your numbers always positive?  Randomly splitting on [+*/-] will not give correct results.  You need to properly parse string using precedence where '* & /' have higher precedence than '+ & -'.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I got your problem right, if you're trying to get each number in your string try this:

```
//string input = "2*5+7/5-424)";
Regex getNumbers = new Regex(@"\b(\d)+\b");

var matchColl = getNumbers.Matches(input);

double[] num = new double[matchColl.Count];
int c = 0;

foreach (Match number in matchColl)
    num[c++] = Convert.ToDouble(number.Value);
```